# How to retrieve android install referrer in Unity3d Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, install-referrer

How to get the game's install referrer on Android.. Android has a built-in `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intent which is broadcasted when app in installed from Play Store, which can be listened in a BroadcastReceiver.. But how do I get the value in my Unity script..

Answer (score 0):

Android intents (much like many other platform-specific things) can't be accessed directly from Unity. You'll have to create an android library with the code to handle the intent, and use a custom manifest in Unity to declare it. It should all be handled within Java, because the Unity/C# context exists only when you have a running activity with a unity player in it, which may not be the case when your app is simply handling an intent without an active activity.

If you need to handle the event in C#, you can launch your activity from your Java code with a custom intent, create another piece of Java code to check the launch intent for any additional custom data from the handler, and invoke that in an Awake method in one of your scripts. It's not the cleanest solution, but it works, and it's the best I could think of to implement custom push notification handling logic.